# Rewrite rules gives inifinite loop (error 500) despite [L] option

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to types of urls. The first one contains number and the second does not, e.g.:

```
/forms/my-forms/form/123/edit
/forms/my-forms/
```

I want to take out all numbers from path (if they have no letters before/after the `/` sings so e.g. `123` but not `a123`) to `$_GET` variable and the rest of the path to another `$_GET` so I will have something like that after rewriting:

```
index.php?path=forms/my-forms/form/edit&id=123
index.php?path=forms/my-forms/
```

I've created the `.htaccess` for this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)(.*)?$ ./index.php?path=$1$3&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

But it gives me infinitive loop (500 Interla Server Error), despite using `[L]` for both rules.

When I remove one of the rules, the other works fine (but of course I only have processing of first or second type of urls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L flag doesn't do what you think it does. L just exists the current Rewrite Cycle and sends the uri for next fase of processing. You are getting rewrite loop error because of your last rule

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

This rewrites everything to **/index.php** , for your example 
in first iteration
http://example.com/foobar gets rewritten to **/index.php?url=foobar** and then , On the second rewrite iteration **/index.php?url=foobar** gets rewritten to itself **/index.php?url=** and thus apache return a 500 Error status to client.
To fix the loop error, you need to tell mod-rewrite to exit the rule processing in first iteration, You can Replace **L** with **END** if you are on apache 2.4 , if you are on lower version of apache you can use the following condition above the rule that is causing internal loops

```
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below rule, I didn't tried for now but `.*` is the one causing problem It matches everything in url and after that most of the rule cease to work other than with `.*`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([0-9]+)(.+?)?$ ./index.php?path=$1$3&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ ./index.php?path=$1 [L]
```